# FFMPEG: Sync problem between audio and video on Live Stream

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

I am using NGINX RTMP as an RTMP server and FFMPEG as a client for live stream. When I connect to the RTMP server with the following command, I get an output file that contains slow motion for almost 5 seconds. But the sound is OK.

```sh
ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://somertmp -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/sometoken -f flv output.mp4
```

As the preceding example shows, I deliver the stream to youtube and at the same time, I get a copy. Youtube does not show slow motions but when I open the file with `ffplay` I can see the problematic frames.

I want to fix these slow motions and make it synced with audio with ffmpeg or if not possible I want to tell ffmpeg to cut those slow frames along with audio channel so video and audio would be synced.

For days, I am trying to find a solution for this problem but unfortunately, I could not. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. On Nginx RTMP side `interleave` and `wait_key` directives should be enabled.